# How to import a variable from a route() decorator to form file in Flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to import a variable that is declared in one of my route decorators for my program to the forms, but the form is used inside of the route.

From my `views.py` function

```
@app.route('/test4', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test4():
    form1=SVN_Path()
    form2=Inputs()
    if request.method=="POST" and form1.validate_on_submit():
        prev_pdf=["test1.pdf","test2.pdf","test3.pdf","test4.pdf","test5.pdf"]
  ----> new_pdf=["ex1.pdf","ex2.pdf"]
        options=[("None","None")]+[(pdf,pdf) for pdf in new_pdf]
        for sub_form in form2.files:
            sub_form.choices= options
            sub_form.default="None"
        return render_template('test4.html',form1=form1,form2=form2,show=True,numfiles=len(prev_pdf),pdflist=prev_pdf)
```

I want to **import the the length of new_pdf** to my forms file which is located in the same directory as my views.py. I know I can get the length using a statement like `lengthpdf=len(new_pdf)` but I'm unsure how to import it to `forms.py` which contains

```
class Inputs(Form):
    files = FieldList(SelectField(u'File', validators =[Required()]),min_entries = 2)
```

where min_entries should be equal to the length of new_pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use [FieldList.append_entry()](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList.append_entry). So instead of specifying `min_entries` at time of `files` definition, you'll just append an entry (like you do with choices for the select fields).

Ex.

```
def test4():
    form2 = Inputs()
    if request.method == "POST" and form1.validate_on_submit():
        prev_pdf = ["test1.pdf", "test2.pdf", "test3.pdf","test4.pdf", "test5.pdf"]
        new_pdf = ["ex1.pdf","ex2.pdf"]
        options = [("None","None")] + [(pdf, pdf) for pdf in new_pdf]
        for i in range(len(new_pdf)):
            form2.files.append_entry()
            form2.files[i].choices = options
            form2.files[i].default = "None"
        return render_template('test4.html', form1=form1, form2=form2, show=True, numfiles=len(prev_pdf), pdflist=prev_pdf)
```

Comment: Yes this does work, however before I was accessing my data using `form2.files.data`, but due to the append_entry change I'm not able to access the data using `form2.files.data` and I get a `'NoneType' object is not iterable` error,

Comment: That should still work. Where are you accessing `form2.files.data`?